# Show/Hide column based on Dropdown selection in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to show a hidden column based on an option of my dropdown. For a single row it works fine but when I want to extend my Range for 10 rows

`If Range("$CF$5: $CF$15") = "Others" Then`

Tt displays a `Runtime error 13.`

Below is my code. Thanks for helping me out.

```
If Range("$CF$5") = "Others" Then
    ActiveSheet.Columns("CG").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    ActiveSheet.Columns("CG").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare the value in the range like you are doing it.

`If Range("$CF$5: $CF$15") = "Others"`

There are many ways to do the comparison. Looping through the range is the most common way. Below is a another way to check if all the cells in a vertical range have the same value.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Set your worksheet here
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Set your range here
        Set rng = .Range("CF5:CF15")

        '~~> Check if any cell in the range have "Others"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "Others") = _
        rng.Rows.Count Then
            .Columns("CG").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
            .Columns("CG").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

And if you want to Show/Hide the column even if there is one instance of "Others` then also you don't need a loop. See this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Set your worksheet here
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Set your range here
        Set rng = .Range("CF5:CF15")

        '~~> Check if all the cells in the range have "Others"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "Others") > 0 Then
            .Columns("CG").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
            .Columns("CG").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Siddharth Rout. Your code is not working on my machine. I wonder if I'm doing something wrong? There could be other options selected in Rows 5 - 15. I mean in Row 5 it could be "others" and in row 6 "Toyota" and so on.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? even if one of them is "Others" you want to show the column? If yes, then see the updated code in my post.

Comment: Is a CountIf faster than a loop?

Comment: @mattboy: Anyday :) In Excel fill the entire col A with say `1`. So it will be 65336 cells in `xl2003` and 1048576 cells in `xl2007+`. Now type `=COUNTIF(A:A,1)` in say `B1` and check how much time does it take to return the value. Try the same thing now with a loop.

Comment: Yup, tried it with a million rows, CountIf sure is faster. Nice one! Although it's not very noticeable when you only have a few rows.

Comment: @mattboy: `Although it's not very noticeable when you only have a few rows.` True that :)

Comment: Thanks Siddharth. Your edited code works perfectly fine and that is what i needed. Thanks again and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

How about this? This assumes that if a single cell in the range is set to "Others" that the CG column will be shown, and if none them are, CG will be hidden. Not sure if that's what you're really after?

```
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("$CF$5:$CF$15")

    If cell = "Others" Then
        ActiveSheet.Columns("CG").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Exit For
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Columns("CG").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If

Next cell
```