# How to hide sections of an excel page depending on drop down list selection

Tags: excel

I currently have a questionnaire sheet in an excel document that is separated into "Part One" and "Part Two". Within these two sections, there are additional questions. "Part One" has 4 questions and "Part Two" has three.

Both "Part One" and "Part Two" are displayed on the same Sheet.

Before beginning "Part One", I have added a Drop Down List that the user can select if they have completed the questionnaire before.

If they select "I have" from the drop down list, then I only want "Part One" of the page to display and "Part Two" to be hidden.

If the user selects "I haven't", then I would like both "Part One" and "Part Two" to display.

How would I approach completing this task?

I have a very basic knowledge of excel so sorry in advance for any obvious questions.

Any support would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does _page_ in "questionnaire page" mean? Do you mean _sheet_, is it a windows form or is it anything else?

Some screen dumps would be very helpful!

Comment: I have just edited the question to clarify. I have a Sheet which has questions on it. I would like to add some screenshots but unfortunately don't have to reputation to do so.

Comment: Alright, I can see you've updated your question. Is "Part One" a different sheet from f ex "Part Two"?  What does _section_ mean in  " ...I would like both sections to display."?

Comment: I have updated the question which should answer your points.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show/Hide column based on Dropdown selection in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444870/show-hide-column-based-on-dropdown-selection-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was forced (!) to accomplish this task on a sheet inside Excel I would probably have looked at @TheEngineer's link in comments section above.

[Here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/561909-visual-basic-applications-hide-named-range.html#post2776561) is another thread with a similar discussion

The key functions would probably have been:

```
Range("XX:YY").EntireRow.Hidden = [True | False]
Range("ZZ:WW").EntireColumn.Hidden = [True | False]
```

Comment: I did receive the answer from the link provided by @TheEngineer's but you posted it as an answer so thank you.